# Trying to access array offset on value of type null (Emailvalidator)

Tags: php, laravel, server

I have a CMS Library manager. All the conection to the DB works properly, it makes new users, new post, delete posts, edit posts... but when I try to click on "I forget my password" and click on send the password by mail, or I try to make a new user account (the user account get created but no active because it doesn't send any verification mail), it shows this error:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type null

in Parser.php line 147
```

If I go to that line, it shows this:

[image]

I attach the full error debug too:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type null

    in Parser.php line 147
    at HandleExceptions->handleError()
    in Parser.php line 147
    at Parser->escaped()
    in Parser.php line 127
    at Parser->isFWS()
    in LocalPart.php line 57
    at LocalPart->parse()
    in EmailParser.php line 48
    at EmailParser->parse()
    in RFCValidation.php line 30
    at RFCValidation->isValid()
    in EmailValidator.php line 37
    at EmailValidator->isValid()
    in IdentificationHeader.php line 182
    at Swift_Mime_Headers_IdentificationHeader->assertValidId()
    in IdentificationHeader.php line 128
    at Swift_Mime_Headers_IdentificationHeader->setIds()
    in IdentificationHeader.php line 99
    at Swift_Mime_Headers_IdentificationHeader->setId()
    in IdentificationHeader.php line 75
    at Swift_Mime_Headers_IdentificationHeader->setFieldBodyModel()
    in SimpleHeaderFactory.php line 141
    at Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderFactory->createIdHeader()
    in SimpleHeaderSet.php line 115
    at Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderSet->addIdHeader()
    in SimpleMimeEntity.php line 217
    at Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->setId()
    in SimpleMessage.php line 53
    at Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage->__construct()
    in Message.php line 48
    at Swift_Message->__construct()
    at ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs()
    in DependencyContainer.php line 330
    at Swift_DependencyContainer->createNewInstance()
    in DependencyContainer.php line 115
    at Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup()
    in Mailer.php line 41
    at Swift_Mailer->createMessage()
    in Mailer.php line 451
    at Mailer->createMessage()
    in Mailer.php line 237
    at Mailer->send()
    in Mailable.php line 159
    at Mailable->Illuminate\Mail\{closure}()
    in Localizable.php line 19
    at Mailable->withLocale()
    in Mailable.php line 160
    at Mailable->send()
    in Mailer.php line 274
    at Mailer->sendMailable()
    in Mailer.php line 229
    at Mailer->send()
    in PendingMail.php line 124
    at PendingMail->send()
    in RegisterController.php line 98
    at RegisterController->register()
    at call_user_func_array()
    in Controller.php line 54
    at Controller->callAction()
    in ControllerDispatcher.php line 45
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
    in Route.php line 219
    at Route->runController()
    in Route.php line 176
    at Route->run()
    in Router.php line 682
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 30
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
    at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
    at SubstituteBindings->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 75
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in StartSession.php line 63
    at StartSession->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in EncryptCookies.php line 66
    at EncryptCookies->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then()
    in Router.php line 684
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack()
    in Router.php line 659
    at Router->runRoute()
    in Router.php line 625
    at Router->dispatchToRoute()
    in Router.php line 614
    at Router->dispatch()
    in Kernel.php line 176
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 30
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in TrustProxies.php line 57
    at TrustProxies->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in TransformsRequest.php line 31
    at TransformsRequest->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in TransformsRequest.php line 31
    at TransformsRequest->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
    at ValidatePostSize->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 62
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
    in Pipeline.php line 163
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
    in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then()
    in Kernel.php line 151
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
    in Kernel.php line 116
    at Kernel->handle()
    in index.php line 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: needed to update the Lavarel version.